# Django Custom Tag Conditional Logic

Tags: django

In this project I'm working with (I'm very new to Django), there are custom tags i.e. `{{ custom_tag }}` that a previous developer created.

In the HTML file, I find myself doing the following block of conditional logic many times in the same HTML file.

```
{% if custom_tag == "Blog Tag" %}
 Blog
{% elif custom_tag == "About Tag" %}
 About
{% else %}
etc...
{% endif %}
```

Are there ways that I can replace all of that conditional logic into something like `{{ custom_tag|pretty }}` or `{{ pretty_custom_tag }}`?

Comment: You should read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own criting a custom filter which would let you use `{{ custom_tag|tag_pretty }}`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

For example:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def pretty_tag(value):
    return value.rpartition(" ")[0]
```

Comment: That is not an answer, is more like the comment I say before.

Comment: Can you clarify how this isn't an answer?

Comment: because is not an exact real solution to the problem. Is more like "read the doc, and learn how to fix it" :)